# Proving open subsets (-1/n,1/n) for n in the natural numbers are uncountable

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to prove (or disprove) that open subsets of the reals in the shape of $A_n= (-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$ for n in the natural numbers are uncountable.

I have seen others seeking more general proof that every open subset of the reals is uncountable. They were often told to find a bijection from $(0,1)$ and onto the subset, however, I am having difficulties creating such a bijection. So I am looking for help finding a bijection.

Comment: Hint: look for a linear function.

Comment: $f(x)=2(x-1/2)/n$

Comment: Consider $\tan(\theta)$ on the appropriate interval to construct a bijection from the interval to all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One bijection from $(0,1)$ to $A_n$ is given by
$$
x\mapsto \frac{2x-1}n
$$
with inverse
$$
y\mapsto \frac{ny+1}2
$$